# non-relational database

Tags: database, database-design

1. What exactly is non-relational database ??i have heard that web-sites like fb, google are using non relational database what is that
2. Under what condition we should use non-relational database
3. What are the advantage of non-relational data base over relational database ..??

Comment: How many books are you willing to read?

Comment: Many of the things that interest you are already covered in these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/nosql/faq

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Answer (score 3):

Objectivity, db4o (open source), etc are called object databases which I *think* you're asking about? Rather than RDBMS they're called ODBMS. There's also the new "cloud databases" but I'm not too familiar with those and I'm not sure they'll be practical/useful for every type of application, even in the distant future. Between those two that's (probably) the two major non-RDBMS db types. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL )

Object dbs are pretty cool, think something like Hibernate, only faster since there isn't a conversion to SQL being done. Object dbs are supposed to be much faster when you have complex/deep data hierarchies. (They're probably also a little faster "in general", but there are some downsides to watch out for.)

One downside to an object database is that it puts more work on developers to sometimes to DBA-like tasks.  (I guess this could be good *or* bad.)  Your traditional Oracle DBAs will be standing around clueless and useless if you use an object db. Some issues include - (at least with db4o) no really powerful tools to help manage the db (RDBMS have a ton of these), a different "schema upgrade" process, and generally it's a less mature type of database. Scalability can be an issue if you're talking about a large system, there's no clustering in db4o or anything like that (yet).

Also, just for completeness, older legacy databases like Adabas or VSAM are considered non-relational.

Comment: Downvoted for what, being the only answer? Did I offend an RDBMS DBA? (he he he - don't worry, RDBMS is not going away even if OO dbs take off)

Answer (score 0):

**1:** The opposite of a relational database is a linear database.

A linear database looks like this: We have one (or more) tables, and each table stores different lists. There is no connection (relation) between those tables. All attributes (columns) of the tables are statically connected in a line (row). In the example below, John is definitely in the gym-group and Alice has nothing to do with Mary.

**Linear database:**

table users
............................................................
uuid    name    group
............................................................
0001    John    gym-group
0002    Mary    reading-group

table others
............................................................
uuid    name
............................................................
0013    Jack
0014    Alice

**Relational database:**

In addition, in a relational database, (it can even be the same tables) we have a relation between the tables.

table users
............................................................
uuid    name
............................................................
0001    John
0002    Mary

table groups
............................................................
uuid    name
............................................................
0037    gym-group
0038    reading-group

To link the relation of the elements, we could have the following relation-table. The UUID (Universal Unique Identification) represents the key/primary-key that must be unique across all tables.

table relation_users_groups
............................................................
uuid    uuid-users    uuid-groups
............................................................
0104    0001            0037
0105    0001            0038
0106    0002            0037
0107    0013            0037
0108    0014            0037

In the relational table we can see, that John (0001) is in the gym-group (0037) AND in the reading-group (0038). Mary (0002) is in the gym-group (0037).

Further we can see, that we have related also the others user table and Jack (0013) and Alice (0014) are now in the same group with Mary.

Finally that means, in a relational database, chunks of information (granularity/size of those does not matter) can be linked relational to each other. (non-static combinations). Independent of the database-program or query-language used.

**2:** non-relational / linear databases or table structures, can be used when a dynamic relation between the elements is not required. A linear approach makes sense if the structure of the application is quite simple. Simple doesn't necessarily mean small.

**3:** One advantage could be that they are more intuitive to read, even within the database without a frontend (GUI). In the example above, rel_users_groups table is quite easy to follow. In reality the tables are not human readable because the UUIDs are long token (hash) like 490c869e-292f-4b0a-be19-92c9dd67d4c7.